Excel summing column with multiple varying criteria ranges
I have the following data:
Data



Data







Criteria A
Criteria B
Criteria C
Value


W10
X50
Jan
14


W10
X51
Jan
12


W10
X53
Jan
10


W20
X51
Jan
10


W20
X50
Feb
20


W20
X50
Feb
12


W20
X50
Feb
19


W20
X51
Mar
11


W20
X51
Mar
14


W30
X51
Apr
11



And the following criteria (example):
Filter Conditions



Criteria A
Criteria B
Criteria C




W10
X50
Jan


W20
X51
Feb




Mar



The criteria lists are always the 3 listed, but there may be more or less values in them.
How can i make a formula summing up the Value column given this situation?
I have tried the following formula:
SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(value;'Criteria A from data;Criteria A from filter;'Criteria B from data;Criteria B from filter;'Criteria C from data;Criteria C from filter))

However, that only works with one column criteria.
In this case i would expect the sum to be 65
Expected result


Here is an "old school method" that works in all versions.
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A11,H2:H9,0)*MATCH(B2:B11,I2:I9,0)*MATCH(C2:C11,J2:J9))*D2:D11)



Thanks, I'll visit the old school (also) in the future ;)

Summing with
SUMPRODUCT = value_col * accumulated(COUNTIF(criteria, data)
by comparing columns in criteria with columns in data with same index; value_col is assumed to be the last column.
If columns are not contiguous, we could use COUNTIFS instead.
=LAMBDA(data, crit,
    LET(
        multiple_countif, LAMBDA(crit, src,
            REDUCE(
                EXPAND(1, ROWS(src), , 1),
                SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(crit)),
                LAMBDA(acc, n,
                    acc *
                        COUNTIF(INDEX(crit, , n), INDEX(src, , n))
                )
            )
        ),
        SUMPRODUCT(TAKE(data, , -1), multiple_countif(crit, data))
    )
)(A2:D11, F2:H4)


